# AJAX innerHTML PHP array and location not working?

Tags: php, ajax, echo

I am making a code where all comments in a database are echoed out with the help of AJAX. Right now I have two problems.

1. Location is not working. Here is my code for opening the xmlHttpRequest.

   ```
   xmlHttp.open("GET", "location.href.split('/').pop();", true);
   ```

   I get the "Not Found" error when I check if the status == 200. But when I use a filename I know is in the directory it works. I must use something like the above because I have a few set variables in the url which makes unique pages.
2. The comments are not echoing out. Here is my

**PHP**

```
<?php

$showcomment=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `photosite`.`comments` WHERE `photo_id`='$photo_id'");
echo '<response>';
while($allcomments=mysql_fetch_array($showcomment)){

    echo '<div id="comment"></div>';
}
echo '</response>';
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
function process(){
    if(xmlHttp){
        try{
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "location.href.split('/').pop();", true);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
            xmlHttp.send(null);     
        }catch(e){
            alert( e.toString() );
        }
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
        comment = document.getElementById('comment');
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            if(xmlHttp.status==200){
                try {
                    comment.innerHTML += "'.$allcomments['firstname'].' '.$allcomments['surname'].' '.$allcomments['comment'].'<br>";
                }catch(e){
                    alert( e.toString() );
        } else {
            alert(xmlHttp.statusText );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the innerHTML all I did was echo out what I had echoed without AJAX. It showed up on the page but as what is is. How do I get it to recognize they are PHP variables? Once they are echoed out on the PHP page shouldn't they become variables?

Comment: You're opening **literally** "location.href.split('/').pop();" as XHR address...?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around your JavaScript expression, otherwise you just get a string. That said, are you trying to send an AJAX requiest to the current page? In that case, just `location.href` would work.

This is probable the source of all your problems, actually.